# How to create a docker image of self-contained dotnet 7 console application

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I have published my console app using this command:

```
dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained.
```

I have created a dockerfile inside the project folder and this is the content of that:

```
FROM scratch
COPY bin/Release/net7.0/win-x64/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["JustForDocker.dll"]
```

- My console app just prints hello world.
- I have tried to build this docker image using the command:

```
docker build -t dockername .
```

- I created the docker image and tried to run it using the command: docker run dockername
- But I cannot see the output I can just see a blank output, nothing else, but it should print hello world as output.

Comment: dll name can not mean anything besides file name unless you use dotnet command. So it should be `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","JustForDocker.dll"]`

Comment: Really a Windows docker image?

Comment: I have published the app as self-contained right? can i skip the "dotnet" command in the entry point as am not including runtime image as base image?

Comment: Then you need an exe. To get an executable you must specify the target platform "-r Plattform" as executables are plattform specific.

Comment: Since you are using "scratch". "self-contained" means the framework bits. But you are still missing anything on the OS bits. "self-contained" does not include an OS.

Comment: Self-contained doesn't mean native. The runtime is included but the runtime's dependencies are *not*. You need to either use the [mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime-deps/) image as a base, or use .NET 7's [Publish as container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/publish-as-container) functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A self-contained .NET app isn't going to work in a `scratch` container without more native dependencies. It's only self-contained in terms of .NET runtime. But the .NET runtime still depends on native libraries such as OpenSSL. Instead, you'll want to make use of the official `runtime-deps` container images produced for .NET: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/README.runtime-deps.md.

So if you change `FROM scratch` to `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:7.0`, that should give you what you're after.

Comment: Then i should include "dotnet" in entrypoint, is this how you are suggesting?
->
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
COPY bin/Release/net7.0/win-x64/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "JustForDocker.dll"]

Comment: No, there is no `dotnet` executable. Sorry, I missed that you had a DLL as your entrypoint. The output of your publish should contain an executable. Use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Self-contained doesn't mean native. The runtime is included but the runtime's dependencies are *not*. You need to either use the [mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime-deps/) image as a base, or use .NET 7's [Publish as container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/publish-as-container) functionality. Another option is to use AOT to produce a native binary.

To use the `runtime-deps` image, change `FROM scratch` to `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:7.0`

To [publish to a container image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/publish-as-container) directly, you need to add the `Microsoft.NET.Build.Containers` package to the project and specify the container image name in `csproj` with the `ContainerImageName` element :

```
...
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ContainerImageName>dotnet-worker-image</ContainerImageName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    ...
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Build.Containers" Version="7.0.401" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

After that, you can publish directly to an image with :

```
dotnet publish --os linux --arch x64 /t:PublishContainer -c Release
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i'll try this way.